# Unity Virtual Joystick does not react

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a virtual joystick in Unity. Somehow, it does not react. The events `OnPointerDown` , `OnPointerUp` and `OnDrag` never get entered by the debugger.

This is a view of my inspector settings

[image: Hierarchy]

[image: Canvas]

[image: Joystick Background]

[image: Joystick Object]

And this is my code, as you can see, I have a data class for some data and call it in the controller class.

```
public class VirtualJoystickData
{
    private Vector3 inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 InputVector { get { return inputVector; } set { inputVector = value; } } // the movementDirection

    private Image joystickBackgroundImage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("JoystickBackGroundImage").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joysticks background
    public Image JoystickBackgroundImage { get { return joystickBackgroundImage; } }

    private Image joystickImage = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Joystick").GetComponent<Image>(); // the joystick object to use
    public Image JoystickImage { get { return joystickImage; } }
}

public class VirtualJoystickController : Monobehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    private VirtualJoystickData data; // reference to the data class

    private void Start()
    {
        data = new VirtualJoystickData();
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData e) // Click the joystick
    {
        OnDrag(e);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData e) // leave the joystick
    {
        data.InputVector = Vector3.zero; // reset joystick
        data.JoystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData e) // drag the joystick
    {
        Vector2 position;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(data.JoystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform, e.position, e.pressEventCamera, out position)) // start dragging it
        {
            position.x = (position.x / data.JoystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            position.y = (position.y / data.JoystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            data.InputVector = new Vector3(position.x * 2 + 1, 0, position.y * 2 - 1);
            data.InputVector = data.InputVector.magnitude > 1 ? data.InputVector.normalized : data.InputVector;

            data.JoystickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(
                data.InputVector.x * (data.JoystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3),
                data.InputVector.z * (data.JoystickBackgroundImage.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));
        }
    }

    public float GetHorizontalInput()
    {
        return data.InputVector.x;
    }

    public float GetVerticalInput()
    {
        return data.InputVector.z;
    }
}
```

Would be awesome, if someone could help me out here. When I try to use the joystick just nothing happens..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The events OnPointerDown , OnPointerUp and OnDrag never get entered by
>   the debugger.

Your scene is likely missing the EventSystem.

To create the EventSystem, go to *GameObject* ---> *UI* ---> *EventSystem*.

It will create an EventSystem GameObject and attach the `EventSystem` and `Standalone Input Module` scripts to it. The callback functions should now be called otherwise put `Debug.Log` inside them to make sure that your statement is correct.

Comment: Np. it's new to some people.